# Why my HTML file doesn't link with my CSS file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code, hyperlink

I'm starting with web development and I have a problem. I want to **link a CSS file to my HTML file, but it doesn't work**. I have asked *ChatGPT* and it tells me that everything is correct, but it still does not work. The code is short and I think it's well written, and I think it's a problem with the app (*Visual Studio Code*). Just in case I leave the code here:

**HTML (index.html):**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Prueba</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>
<body>

    <h1 style="color:red">Esto es un archivo de pruebas</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS (styles.css):**

```css
body{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Change the name file
Try that code in another HTML/CSS/JavaScript interpreter
Change the text in both files for possible mistakes

Comment: What does your file structure look like?

Comment: Does your CSS file is located in document root? And forget that ChatGPT, first learn basics by yourself, e.g. how to check from where browser tries to load your `styles.css`

Answer (score 0):

Have you already checked if your index.html and styles.css files are in a same folder/level? One reason can be that in `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">` href attribute has wrong path to the styles file.

Comment: All the folders and files are in a folder named "main". Then in that folder are two folders: ".vscode" wich has the settings of the app, and the folder "Index" wich has the files "index.html" and "styles.css"

Comment: @MiguelÁngel, I tried your folder structure with your `index.html` and `styles.css` files. Loaded for me, Have you tried to create a new project in VS Code and copy over the files? Just the html and css files and see if that resolves the issue.